# TFS build definition won't load custom activities after upgrade to VS2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, build-definition

I'm having issues with loading a build definition after install of VS2015 which I believe to be the cause.

It complains that it couldn't load the assemblies for some of our custom activities. Is there any way to find out what the "actual" reason and which assembly it was. I'm thinking it's due to it linking to V12.0 versions of TFS assemblies, with VS2015 VS14.0 as priority in the GAC.

Has anyone had any experience of this kind of problem? Or know where I should be looking for the error? I can't see anything in the event viewer logs.

Cheers,
Jamie

**Edit:** They are custom assemblies for our custom activities which fit in each of the 'Advanced' panels.

[image: Errors from the build definition]

Comment: Are those custom libraries that it can't load?  I assume they are because you have the first part of the name blanked out.

Comment: Sorry yes there are, I'll make that clear in the question.

Comment: Is the version control path for the custom assemblies set properly in the build controller?

Comment: Yes the version path is set correctly, other people can access this fine using VS2013. And I could a month or so back assuming it stopped working after VS2015 install

Comment: What account is the build controller running under?  Does it have access to that path?  Are the build agents running under that same account?

Comment: The paths are all consistent, it has access to the location and is running under an account which does have ACL priviledges. It's worth noting the issue I'm seeing is through a local installation of VS2013/5 which tries to access the path from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rebuild your custom workflow activities against the latest version of the reference assemblies and very likely update the .NET version. This is one of many reasons why I've always recommended against creating custom build activities.

Comment: Would VS2015 use a local copy of the custom activities from my workspace or would it go to the server, download them into %AppData%\Temp\VsTfsBuild and use from there?

 I'm trying to avoid destroying everyone else's installation, but something to bare in mind when everyone in my company moves to 2015.

Comment: You would put them in the folder specified in the build service for custom assemblies. They are retrieved for you when you load the build process template.